# How do I give an AWS Cognito Userpool Access to perform an action on an AWS Resource (SES)

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito to authenticate user in my app. In their documentation AWS says that the credentials of a logged in user can be used to give access to AWS resources.

I want to use SES to allow user to submit a contact us form from within the app.

I am able to get the user credentials. However, when I use them for the `AmazonSimpleEmailServiceClient` and call `sendEmail()` I get the following Exception:

> com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: User `arn:aws:sts::xxxxxx/CognitoIdentityCredentials' is not authorized to perform`ses:SendEmail' on resource `arn:aws:ses:xxxxxx' (Service: AmazonSimpleEmailService; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx)

How can I allow the Cognito user pool to call `sendEmail()` so I do not need to store any secrets in my apps code?

Answer (score 0):

To give access to users for AWS resources, it requires to setup Cognito Federated Identities in addition to Cognito Userpools.

In Cognito Federated Identities, connect the relevant Cognito Userpool and create the IAM Role policy for authenticated users to include AWS SES access.